# C# Socket Receive: Taking in data until buffer is full dilemma

Tags: c#, sockets, buffer, freeze, receiver

Here is my code I'm having an issue with:

```
// read the file in chunks of 5KB
var buffer = new byte[1024*5];
int bytesRead = 0;
do
{
    bytesRead = host.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, 0);
    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
while (bytesRead == buffer.Length);
```

So here's my problem: I want to read in data as long as the buffer is full. However, even if there is more data, the buffer isn't guaranteed to be filled when sending. This causes the Receive to prematurely exit. If I change the while condition to `bytesRead > 0` then it reaches the end of data and Receive blocks until more data is available (which it won't be). How do I solve this?

Comment: _"and Receive blocks until ..."_  - why? Because it shouldn't.

Comment: As Henk said "it shouldn't". If you reach end of data you are done reading so you should not try to read anymore? I think you need to clarify more what you mean. Why do you want to continue to read when there is no more data?

Comment: @FSDaniel I don't. But according to MDSN the Socket.Receive call will block when no data is left. Is there a way around that? I know I can do a timeout but that won't work for every transmission.

Comment: If you make a call to host.Receive and it returns a number less then buffer.Length you have no more data to read and should not need to call it again (causing it to block). (Of course there could be more data later on that all depends on how the protocol works but for now there should be no more data).

Comment: bytesRead can be less that buffer.Length. When happens this shows bytesReceived are less than what buffer can handle. Thats why you use bytesRead in output.write instead of buffer.Length.

Comment: Also why you want to read data until buffer if full. What is that data that you are trying to figure out.

Comment: I have same issue.  Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to think about how the protocol works and make a more robust solution. Either you go with blocking and then you could either wait until you have no more data to read and then do something else and read again when you know you have more data to read.

Or you add threading and have a seperate thread that just reads and then it doesn't matter if it blocks since it will be on a seperate thread.

Another solution that might be simpler is to use asynchronous reads.

You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx

A simple example from the site above is to start with the read:

```
private static void Receive(Socket client) {
    try {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you will get a callback to ReceiveCallback when there is data to be handled:

```
private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
    try {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;
        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));
                //  Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        } else {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1) {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I hope this works if not we need to know more about what protocol you use and if there is some reason you need blocking reads so we can give more specific information and help.